# How to enable IOMMU on Guest

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, iommu

I am planning to perform nested virtualization with GPU device. I have guest Ubuntu OS running and I have mapped GPU to it by enabling intel_iommu on the host, and configuring NVIDIA PCI as vfio-pci device. I am also able to install NVIDIA driver on the guest and use it for deep-learning.

However, now I want to run another VM inside the guest, let's call the guest that runs on host as L1 and the guest that runs on guest as L2, I want the GPU to be accessiable by the L2 guest, I came across vIOMMU supported on Q35 Qemu chipset, how do I enable IOMMU on L1 guest, so that I can pass the gpu directly to L2 guest??

Hardware :
Intel i7 8th Gen 
NVIDIA GeForce 1070
Linux - Ubuntu 18.04, 
Hypervisor - KVM

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to be done on KVM-QEMU to allow nested IOMMU

1. Use BIOS `OVMF.fd`, because default bios might not support the same
2. enable the chipset **q35** with `accel=kvm,kernel_irqchip=split`

then check with `dmesg | grep -e DMAR -e IOMMU` and `find /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/ -type l`, for iommu groups inside the VM.